# Better way to check the checkbox value

Tags: c#, checkbox, boolean

I wrote a piece of code that checks 3 checkboxes from a window if they are all checked or all unchecked.

1. Is there a better way to write this?
2. If the checkboxes are not all checked or unchecked at the same time, what is a better way to do my IF statements?

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

**The code the calls and compares the checkboxes value:**

```
public void TheCheckboxesShouldBeChecked()
{
   bool estCheckboxStatus = Win1.GetCheckboxstatus();
   bool checkboxStatus = true;
   Assert.AreEqual(checkboxStatus, estCheckboxStatus, "Checkbox values did not match the default.");
}

public void TheCheckboxesShouldBeUnChecked()
{
   bool estCheckboxStatus2 = Win1.GetCheckboxstatus2();
   bool checkboxStatus2 = true;
   Assert.AreEqual(checkboxStatus2, estCheckboxStatus2, "Checkbox values did not match the default.");
}
```

**The code that checks and returns the values of the checkboxes:**

```
public bool GetCheckboxstatus()
{
   bool value = false;
   if (ChkBx1.Checked
      && ChkBx2.Checked 
      && ChkBx3.Checked)
   {
      value = true;
      return value;
   }
   else
   {
      return value;
   }

 public bool GetCheckboxstatus2()
{
   bool value = true;
   if (ChkBx1.Checked
      && ChkBx2.Checked 
      && ChkBx3.Checked)
   {
      value = false;
      return value;
   }
   else
   {
      return value;
   }
```

Comment: What do you expect as result if all are unchecked?

Comment: I'm doing this as part of an automated test. I have a code that sets the checkboxes to be checked/unchecked from a default settings window. Now this code above should check if the changes a master user made (e.g. checks all checkboxes) is applied on each individual user page correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first question, yes there is:

**In your testing class:**

```
public void TheCheckboxesShouldBeChecked()
{
    AssertCheckState(Win.AreAllCheckboxesChecked());
}

public void TheCheckboxesShouldBeUnChecked()
{
    AssertCheckState(Win.AreAllCheckboxesUnchecked());
}

private void AssertCheckState(bool value)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(true, actual, "Checked state does not match");
}
```

**In your `Win1` class:**

```
public bool AreAllCheckboxesChecked
{
    return (ChkBx1.Checked && ChkBx2.Checked && ChkBx3.Checked);
}

public bool AreAllCheckboxesUnchecked()
{
    return (!ChkBx1.Checked && !ChkBx2.Checked && !ChkBx3.Checked);
}
```

As for your second concern, really it's up to you and what you need. You could expose individual check states encapsulated in the class properties for example.

Comment: You're welcome. Please do not forget to mark this thread as answered when you are done. Thanks. :)

Comment: I incorporated this to my code and it worked well and it looked much clearer and streamlined now. Thanks so much! I'm just learning so all help to make mine better is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

To determine if **all** are checked:

```
return ChkBx1.Checked && ChkBx2.Checked && ChkBx3.Checked;
```

To determine if **none** are checked then:

```
return !ChkBx1.Checked && !ChkBx2.Checked && !ChkBx3.Checked;
```

For anything more detailed - i.e., *which* are checked and unchecked - then logic naturally starts to look a little ugly.

Comment: so for the "all are checked" line you wrote, if the 3 checkboxes are checked, then it will return a "true" value otherwise it will return false like if one is unchecked?

Comment: Yes ...the same as the `if(...)` statement you have in your question. There is no need for the extra variable and `else` block just for this.